Does the second Bourgain–Delbaen space belong to C_p?
The second Bourgain–Delbaen space $Y$ is a separable $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ space such that  $Y$ contains no copy of $c_0$ or $\ell_1$. The dual space is isomorphic to $\ell_1$.
An operator $T:X\to Y$ is $p$-convergent if it takes weakly $p$-summable sequences to norm null ones.
A Banach space $X\in C_p$ if the identity map $i$ on $X$ is $p$-convergent.
It is known that $X\in C_p$ if and only if every operator $T:\ell_{p^*}\to X$ is compact, where $p^*$ is the conjugate of $p$.
Is $Y\in C_p$ for some $1<p<\infty$ ? Is $Y\in C_2$?

There are many Bourgain-Delbaen spaces. For each $1<p<\infty$, there is one that is hereditarily $\ell_p$. See Haydon's paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm139/sm13935.pdf

Thanks for the paper. I should have asked: if $Y$ is a separable $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ space that does not contain $c_0$ and $\ell_1$ and whose dual is isomorphic to $\ell_1$, do we know if $Y\in C_p$, for some $1<p<\infty$? In particular, can we say if $Y\in C_2$?

If by a B-D space we mean a $ \mathcal L_\infty $space with separable dual  and the question is if such a space belongs to some $C_p$ then the answer must be negative due to the following result. Every reflexive space is embedded into a $ \mathcal L_\infty $ space with separable dual.(see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123611003727?ref=cra_js_challenge&fr=RR-1 ).

I mean $Y$ is a separable $\mathcal{L}\infty$  space whose dual is isomorphic to $\ell_1$ constructed in the paper ``A Special class of $\mathcal{L}\infty$ spaces, by J. Bourgain and F. Delbaen, Acta Math 145 (1980), 155-176.

Is $\ell_2$ embedded in $Y$ by Theorem 4.2 in the paper? Then $Y\not \in C_2$ and thus $Y\not \in C_p$, $p\ge 2$.

The B-D spaces with separable dual are depended by two parameters $\alpha, \beta $ and they are $\ell_r$ saturated where the $r$ is depended by $\alpha, \beta $. It seems that the following holds. Every weakly null sequence in the $\ell_r$ saturated space has a subsequence admitting a lower $\ell_r$ estimate.For more related to this see  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0579. If this is true then indeed every such a space belongs to some $C_p$.

Is it standard terminology to group these spaces into a set (well, proper class) and use $C_p$ as a noun? I have to say, almost always properties of structures (groups, rings, Banach spaces) are just left as adjectives.

Since my last comment is not completely clear I will add an answer which clarifies a little more the content of the comment.
The following holds.
Proposition: Let $X_{a,b}$ be the B–D space built on the parameters $a$, $b$. Let also $r >0$ such that $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{r'}=1$ and $a^{r'} +b^{r'} = 1$. Then every seminormalized weakly null sequence in
$X_{a,b}$ has a subsequence that admits a lower $\ell_r$ estimate.
The proof of the proposition follows from Proposition 4.4 and Proposition 6.4
in Gasparis, Papadiamantis, and Zisimopoulou - More $\ell_r$ saturated $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ spaces, mentioned above, and a standard sliding hump argument for the weakly null sequence.
Now it follows that $X_{a,b} \in C_p$ with $p'>r$.
